# how to design a html 5 dropdown

Tags: html, css, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I am designing a website using vue.js (vue-cli3) and, 
I am in need of designing a select list, that looks similar to the below image[image]

I have currently done some minor designing like, changing the arrow icon, etc. i would like to know if there are any dropdown packages that can be used or if some one can point out any tutorials that i can refer to design an `html select`.

Comment: A rather broad question.  Basically you are designing a site, and don't know how to design.   Have you tried that thing... whats it called... Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem, you should have a look at : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp
or : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click

For your future problems of that sort, you should have a look throughout [w3schools.com](https://w3schools.com)'s entire website. You'll probably find almost everything you are looking for!